# What corner case am I missing in my algorithm to find the largest palindromic number from at most K digit replacements?

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

I've been working on this for hours and my solution is meeting the performance benchmarks and is passing almost all the test cases. It is O(n) and is pretty well described in the comments. Unfortunately the test cases are so gigantic that it's impossible to step through them, and so I'm hoping one of you can provide a fresh set of eyes to see if I'm maybe missing a corner case here.

```
static string LargestPalindromeAfterKReplacements(string number, int k)
{
    // Finds the largest palindromic number (digits are the same in reverse order)
    // that can be formed by at most k replacements of digits.
    // e.g. "001", k=2 --> "909"
    //      "001", k=1 --> "101"
    //      "001", k=0 --> "-1" (not possible)

    // Get number as a StringBuilder element
    var sb = new StringBuilder(number);

    // For the first pass through the string, replace any of the unequal
    // characters on the left and right side by the larger of the two. For
    // later use, keep track of the left index of each of these replacements.
    var replacementIndices = new Queue<int>(); 
    for(int i = 0, j = sb.Length - 1; i < j && k > 0; ++i, --j)
    {
        if(sb[i] < sb[j])
        {
            sb[i] = sb[j];
            replacementIndices.Enqueue(i);
            k -= 1;
        }
        else if(sb[i] > sb[j])
        {
            sb[j] = sb[i];
            replacementIndices.Enqueue(i);
            k -= 1;
        }
    } 

    // If sb isn't a palindrome at this point, then it was never possible to
    // make it one. 
    if(!IsPalindrome(sb.ToString()))
        return "-1";

    // If here, sb is a palindrome. If we have any k left over, then for any of
    // the indices where we made a replacement, if the pair isn't already both 9, 
    // we coudld've made them both 9 during the first pass through the string, at
    // a cost decreasing k by 2 rather than by 1. "Replay" the original pass like this.
    while(k > 0 && replacementIndices.Count > 0) 
    {
        int i = replacementIndices.Dequeue(), j = sb.Length - i - 1;
        if(sb[i] != '9')
        {
            sb[i] = '9';
            sb[j] = '9';
            k -= 1;
        }
    }

    // In case we still have k > 0, that means we ran out of replacementIndices.
    // Make a third pass through the string and make any non-equal characters
    // on opposite ends become 9. 
    for(int i = 0, j = sb.Length - 1; i <= j && k > 0; ++i, --j)
    {
        if(sb[i] != '9')
        {
            if(k > 1)
            {
              sb[i] = '9';
              sb[j] = '9'; 
              k -= 2;
            }
            else if(i == j) // k = 1 and i = j
            {
                sb[i] = '9';
            }
        }
    }

    // In case we ran out of replacement indices, 
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: You should first make the corner digits to be equal to 9, those are not necessarily the ones that were replaced.

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. Does your code in fact produce incorrect results for some specific input? If so, what input is that? What are the results for that input? What result did you expect instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abishek Bansal's comment is right: For example if sb = "1234561" and k = 4, you will first use 2 substitions to move to "1654561" (which is correct so far) -- but then from there to "1994991" instead of to "9654569", because your `while` loop prefers cheap changes to better changes.

But there is a second bug: Why, in your final loop, do you only try modifying the middle (`i == j`) digit if k == 1?  This means that, e.g., for the input sb = "121" and k = 4, your algorithm will return "929", when clearly "999" is possible.  (For a similar counterexample but with k <= n, consider the input sb = "929" and k = 2.)

Finally: The easiest way to debug code like this is to generate *all possible instances below a certain size* (or at least many of them) and compare the output of your algorithm with the output of a known-good (e.g. brute-force) algorithm on each of them, stopping as soon as you hit an input with different outputs.  This will (usually) give you an example small enough to analyse manually.